# .htaccess: Redirect short link to main URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have multiple links like this:

```
www.example.com/my_folder/some_title/12
www.example.com/my_folder/any_title/56
www.example.com/my_folder/something/32
```

To make it easier for my users I want to create short links like this:

```
www.example.com/12
www.example.com/56
www.example.com/32
```

Means: If I type `www.example.com/12` I want it to redirect to `www.example.com/my_folder/any_placeholder/12`.

Means: If the URL has only a single number as path, (301?) redirect it to `my_folder/any_placeholder/12`.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: You could use apache rewrites. For more info see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On   

RewriteRule ^\d+/?$ my_folder/any_placeholder/$0 [L]
```

Comment: You're unbelievable. Thank you very much for helping me again. (That's all for now.)